# Asp.net sending a dotx(word template) to client side

Tags: asp.net, ms-word

In my program, I need to send a dotx to client side. Now I process it as:

1. generate the temp dotx in server side which contains some data from database.
2. send it to client side. The code is:

   ```
           Response.Clear();
           Response.Buffer = true;
           Response.Charset = "unicode";
           Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template";
           Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=**.dotx");
           Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", dataWord.Length.ToString());
           Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
           Response.BinaryWrite(dataWord);
           Response.Flush();
           Response.Close();
   ```

   dataWord is the dotx.
3. delete the temp dotx.

This process should be correct. But sometimes I only get a blank document in client side. I am sure the dotx generated in server side is not blank. What may cause that problem? Does error happen during sending data to client-side with Response, or is my code not good?

Comment: Well, thats hard to answer, why dont you add a line of code and save the file on the server to see if it is being produced properly. Keep an audit trail of sorts and figure that out first.

Comment: Hi Kell, sorry, I did not post all my code. Actually, I had done as you mentioned. When I get the blank doc in client-side, I could also find the corresponding dotx in server-side and it was not blank.

Comment: I don't see how this could work when 'dataWord' I assume is a string pointing to your .dotx file? If so, then BinaryWrite() expects a buffer byte[], not a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found doing numerous different versions of this that writing an actual file to the server and then sending via Response.TransmitFile to be far far more robust.

By doing so you also have an extra debug step you can use for now by checking the files manually on the server to see if they are blank and possibly spotting other issues.

Comment: Hi Justing, thanks. I have done as you said. I am sure the dotx generated in server-side is not blank. Did you have similar experiences?

Comment: By the way, it works correctly in my local machine. That error only occurs in our server after publishing it.

Comment: Can you response.redirect to the file?

Comment: thx. the problem is fixed. I use a pop-up window for user to download the dotx.

Answer (score 0):

Think you must have a valid filename and not **.dotx

Comment: I used guid as the name, not **. The asterisk is only in this post. :)